# Notify when RDFa is used, then display the triples in a human-readable way

Tags: open-source, html, firefox, rdf

I’m looking for a free/libre Firefox add-on (not a bookmarklet/userscript):

I want to get **notified** when the current page contains **RDFa** markup, for example by highlighting an icon in the interface (similar to how the feed icon works).

By clicking on this icon, it should **show** me the extracted **RDF** triples in a friendly format, for example as Turtle or a simple table.

Bonus points for detecting/parsing Turtle (and other RDF serializations) in `script` elements ([used as data blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428316/1591669)).

#### What I found

- There are two Firefox add-ons [tagged with RDFa](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/tag/rdfa), [**Semantic Radar**](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/semantic-radar/) and [**RDFa Developer**](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/rdfa-developer/), but both seem to be inactive (last releases long before RDFa 1.1 was published).
- For Firefox there is [**Fuzz**](https://github.com/msporny/fuzz), but it’s inactive, too.
- For Chrome/Safari there is [**Green Turtle**](https://github.com/alexmilowski/green-turtle), but there doesn’t seem to be a Firefox version.
- For Firefox there is [**Tabulator**](https://github.com/linkeddata/tabulator-firefox) (not available as direct extension download), which I have not tested yet.

Comment: The [OpenLink Structured Data Sniffer](http://osds.openlinksw.com/) might be a solution in the future (currently it only works with the Developer Edition or the Nightly versions).